# how to extract the detected region in opencv?

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, image-processing

Everyone. I have shown below my code for tracking objects and it shows background subtraction result also. Here I am using frame differencing method. now my problem is that I have to extract that moving object from the color video file. I have done segmentation. But for detection I want to extract the region on which I have drawn bounding box. So can anybody help me in this...please. thank you in advance.

```
 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
               {



                CvSize imgSize;
            //CvCapture *capture =     cvCaptureFromFile("S:\\offline object detection database\\video1.avi");
            CvCapture *capture =     cvCaptureFromFile("S:\\offline object detection database\\SINGLE PERSON Database\\Walk1.avi");

                if(!capture){
                 printf("Capture failure\n");
                 return -1;
                }

                 IplImage* frame=0;
                 frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);           
                 if(!frame)
         return -1;

                 imgSize = cvGetSize(frame);

                 IplImage* greyImage = cvCreateImage( imgSize, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
                 IplImage* colourImage;
                 IplImage* movingAverage = cvCreateImage( imgSize, IPL_DEPTH_32F, 3);
                 IplImage* difference;
                 IplImage* temp;
                 IplImage* motionHistory = cvCreateImage( imgSize, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);

                 CvRect bndRect = cvRect(0,0,0,0);
                 CvPoint pt1, pt2;
                 CvFont font;
                 int prevX = 0;
                 int numPeople = 0;
                 char wow[65];
                 int avgX = 0;
                 bool first = true;                   
                 int closestToLeft = 0;
                 int closestToRight = 320;


                 for(;;)
                {
                colourImage = cvQueryFrame(capture);
                if( !colourImage )
                {
                     break;
                }
                if(first)
                {
                 difference = cvCloneImage(colourImage);
                 temp = cvCloneImage(colourImage);
                 cvConvertScale(colourImage, movingAverage, 1.0, 0.0);
                 first = false;
                }
                else
                {
                cvRunningAvg(colourImage, movingAverage, 0.020, NULL);
                }
                cvConvertScale(movingAverage,temp, 1.0, 0.0);
            cvAbsDiff(colourImage,temp,difference);     
                cvCvtColor(difference,greyImage,CV_RGB2GRAY);       
                cvThreshold(greyImage, greyImage, 80, 250, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
        cvSmooth(greyImage, greyImage,2);
                cvDilate(greyImage, greyImage, 0, 1);
                cvErode(greyImage, greyImage, 0, 1);
        cvShowImage("back", greyImage);
                CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
                CvSeq* contour = 0;     
                cvFindContours( greyImage, storage, &contour, sizeof(CvContour), CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );

        for( ; contour != 0; contour = contour->h_next )
                {
                bndRect = cvBoundingRect(contour, 0);          
            pt1.x = bndRect.x;
                pt1.y = bndRect.y;
                pt2.x = bndRect.x + bndRect.width;
                pt2.y = bndRect.y + bndRect.height;         
                avgX = (pt1.x + pt2.x) / 2;

                if(avgX > 90 && avgX < 250)
                {
                if(closestToLeft >= 88 && closestToLeft <= 90)
                {
                 if(avgX > prevX)
                {
                 numPeople++;
                 closestToLeft = 0;
                }
                }
                else if(closestToRight >= 250 && closestToRight <= 252)
                {
                if(avgX < prevX)
                {
                numPeople++;
                closestToRight = 220;
                }
                }                          
                cvRectangle(colourImage, pt1, pt2, CV_RGB(255,0,0), 1);
                }
                if(avgX > closestToLeft && avgX <= 90)
                {
                 closestToLeft = avgX;
                 }
                 if(avgX < closestToRight && avgX >= 250)
                 {
                 closestToRight = avgX;
                 }
                 prevX = avgX;
                 }
                 cvInitFont(&font, CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, 0.8, 0, 2);
                 cvPutText(colourImage, _itoa(numPeople, wow, 10), cvPoint(60, 200), &font, cvScalar(0, 0, 300));
                 cvShowImage("My Window", colourImage);
         cvShowImage("fore", greyImage); 
                 cvWaitKey(10);                     
                  }
                  cvReleaseImage(&temp);
                  cvReleaseImage(&difference);
                  cvReleaseImage(&greyImage);
                  cvReleaseImage(&movingAverage);
                  cvDestroyWindow("My Window");
                  cvReleaseCapture(&capture);   
                  return 0;     
                  }
```

Comment: Too much code. Bad formatting. Who would bother going through it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OpenCV's legacy C API, you can extract a region of interest from an image with [this](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html?#setimageroi) command. In your code you would simply add this line, and the image would be treated as if it contained only the extracted region, pretty much:

```
cvSetImageROI(colourImage, bndrect);
```

In the OpenCV 2.0 API, your old image and "extracted region" image would be stored in separate Mat objects, but point to the same data:

```
Mat colourImage, extractedregion;
colourImage = imread("test.bmp");
extractedregion = colourImage(bndRect);  // Creates only a header, no new image data
```

Many helpful OpenCV tutorials use the legacy API, but you should privilege the new one.

Comment: thank you so much..but I am not getting anything I used cvSetImageROI. but I am not getting anything. can you please tell where I am stuck....thank you..

Comment: How would I do that? I don't have your code (and I certainly won't read it if it's as long and unformatted as the wall in your question!) and I tested that the command works. Replace bndrect with a dummy "Rect(200,200,200,200)" to check if something else is going wrong in your code. Locate the error instead of just saying "I'm stuck, why?". Otherwise, no one will be able to help you.

Comment: hey...I tried..the problem is that I am not able to post an image to give you better idea.I am sorry for my silly reply. I tried but the extrected window shows same as tracking bounding box result .It also gets blank sometimes. Its not stable.I hope you will get idea of this..thank you

Comment: If you call cvSetImageROI(colourImage, bndrect), then display colourImage and see only the part of the image that is inside the bounding box, isn't that what you wanted? Maybe you should make your question clearer and also throw out half of the code.

Comment: ' if(avgX < prevX)
                    {
                    numPeople++;
                    closestToRight = 220;
                    }
                    }
  
    //cvShowImage("Extracted", colourImage);
            cvRectangle(colourImage, pt1, pt2, CV_RGB(255,0,0), 1);
    cvSetImageROI(colourImage,bndRect);
    cvShowImage("Extracted", colourImage);
   //cvShowImage("Extracted", colourImage);
         } `

Comment: I have done this..I am not able to post code..I dont know how to do that.sry for for my bad formating. usig this I am getting extraction window but its blinking and showing some part of the video...thanx for help so far..thnak you

Comment: You're not supposed to dump your code here - you should ask specific questions *about* your code. Read the FAQ to learn what a good question is, and then maybe post another one if you have pinned down a problem that you can't solve. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

I know how to do it with the new OpenCV interface, rather than the "legacy" interface you are using.
It would be like this:

```
cv::Mat frame_m(frame);
...

cv::Mat region_m = frame_m(cv::Rect(bndRect));
IplImage region = region_m; // use &iplimg when an IplImage* is needed.
```

If you don't want to mix interfaces, it is time to learn the new one.

Comment: hey thanx for the reply but I am not getting it..can you please explain it how to use it? thanx

Comment: Can't you do some research on your own? Like reading the very first tutorial on the documentation? It's one of the most important parts of the whole library: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html#matthebasicimagecontainer

Comment: Hi. I have done so many research. and I have learned on my own this library and imlemented this object detection project. its just that I wanted to do more so ask if somebody knows more than me...thanx for the help so far....thank you.

Comment: To use the new API you read the docs, you try it out, then you look at the opencv source to figure out the gaps. THEN you ask here, but you probably won't need to.